# Unmet dependencies for Groovy on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a problem with Groovy install on Ubuntu 12.10. When I type

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
```

I get :

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-desktop-full : Depends: ros-groovy-ros-tutorials (= 0.3.9-0quantal-20121230-1232-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-nodelet-core (= 1.7.13-0quantal-20121230-1911-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation-tutorials (= 0.1.1-s1356945732~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1356894174~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1356865696~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-filters (= 1.6.0-s1356894312~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1356944956~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-ros (= 1.9.39-0quantal-20121230-1040-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-qt-gui-core (= 0.2.9-0quantal-20121230-1144-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-vision-opencv (= 1.9.14-0quantal-20121230-2323-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-perception-pcl (= 1.0.24-0quantal-20121230-1955-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-common-plugins (= 0.2.7-0quantal-20121231-2005-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-actionlib (= 1.9.11-0quantal-20121230-1206-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-pluginlib (= 1.9.17-0quantal-20121230-1110-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-pipeline (= 1.9.11-0quantal-20121230-2354-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1356865809~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-stage (= 1.6.7-s1356894745~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-robot-plugins (= 0.2.7-0quantal-20121231-2000-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-common (= 1.9.22-0quantal-20121230-1342-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-bond-core (= 1.7.9-0quantal-20121230-1142-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1356896830~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-ros-comm (= 1.9.39-0quantal-20121230-1801-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1356864560~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-driver-common (= 1.6.4-0quantal-20121230-1912-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1356894288~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-common-msgs (= 1.9.11-0quantal-20121225-1907-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.5.29-0quantal-20121230-1449-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.15-0quantal-20121230-2344-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1356894606~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model (= 1.9.32-0quantal-20121230-1900-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-bullet (= 2.80-s1356864740~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-visualization-tutorials (= 0.7.3-s1356911662~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry (= 1.9.27-0quantal-20121230-1345-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-documentation (= 1.5.3-s1356894297~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-laser-pipeline (= 1.5.5-s1356905138~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo (= 1.7.6-s1356899063~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.4-s1356894142~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1356864897~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rviz (= 1.9.18-0quantal-20121230-2316-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-diagnostics (= 1.7.9-0quantal-20121230-1415-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-navigation (= 1.10.1-s1356943080~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1356894526~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51272/unmet-dependencies-for-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.10/) by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2012-12-31

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-02**:
Please make sure you have done an apt-get update recently.  And then try to narrow down exactly which package is failng.  Apt is bad in that it just tells you something is failing, not which specific package is failing.

**Comment by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) on 2013-01-03**:
Thanks, but I did the apt-get update. What is a good way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did install it using aptitude, by installing / downgrading the dependencies one by one.

---

Originally posted by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) with karma: 123 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2014-03-12**:
could you share more details on the use of aptitude? is it a time consuming work? should I be better downgrade my Linux to Precise? Thank you!

**Comment by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) on 2014-03-13**:
You don't need to downgrade you Ubuntu to precise. 13.04 should work fine.
Aptitude would give you more details on the required packages (and their versions). So you can install the package if it is missing, or downgrade to the required version by typing:  sudo aptitude install  pkg=version.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. That will force all packages to be updated and might ask you to remove packages which dependencies are not met anymore.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1